# How can I add a Dialog View Controller as a Subview to a UIView or Vice Versa?

Tags: view, dialog, controller, xamarin.ios, subview

I have looked around the web for some time looking for any resources on this topic and have come up with nothing that solves my dilemma.

I have a dialog view controller and its root is simply displaying a list of strings similar to how the iphone music song scrollable view is laid out. What I need is a subview located at the top of the screen and the scrollable DVC below it. I need to the top view to be always in view while the user can scroll through the root element because the top view will be holding statistics.

I have tried adding a subview but it simply overlaps the dvc below it, and I have not been able to figure out a way to add a dvc as a subview to a UIView.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is needed to achieve this is a single root view controller that hosts two subview controllers.  One subview contains the statistics at the top of the window.  The bottom subview contains a navigation controller that holds the dialog view.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;
using System.Drawing;

namespace delete201205203
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;
        MyUIViewController _mvc;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            _mvc = new MyUIViewController ();

            window.RootViewController = _mvc;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MyUIViewController : UIViewController
    {
        MyDialogViewController _dvc;
        UINavigationController _nav;
        StatisticsViewController _statistics;

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            var root = new RootElement ("Root") {
                new Section ("Section") {
                    new EntryElement ("caption", "placeholder", ""),
                    new RootElement ("Root 2") {
                        new Section ("Section") {
                            new EntryElement ("caption", "placeholder", ""),
                            new StringElement ("Back", () => {
                                _nav.PopViewControllerAnimated (true);  
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            _dvc = new MyDialogViewController (root);
            _nav = new UINavigationController (_dvc);
            _nav.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, false);
            _nav.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 70f,
                                              this.View.Bounds.Width, 
                                              this.View.Bounds.Height -70f);

            _statistics = new StatisticsViewController ();
            _statistics.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0,
                                              this.View.Bounds.Width, 
                                              70f);

            this.AddChildViewController (_nav);
            this.View.AddSubview (_nav.View);

            this.AddChildViewController (_statistics);
            this.View.AddSubview (_statistics.View);
        }

        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();
            _nav.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 70f,
                                              this.View.Bounds.Width, 
                                              this.View.Bounds.Height -70f);

            _statistics.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0,
                                              this.View.Bounds.Width, 
                                              70f);
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class StatisticsViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UILabel _label;
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            _label = new UILabel (new RectangleF (this.View.Bounds.Width * .5f - 50f,
                                                  this.View.Bounds.Height * .5f -10f,
                                                  100f, 20f));
            _label.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;

            _label.Text = "statistics";
            this.View.AddSubview (_label);

        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // This overrde is needed to ensure the pop view animation  
    // works correctly in landscape mode
    public class MyDialogViewController : DialogViewController
    {
        public MyDialogViewController (RootElement root) : base (root) {}
        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did exactly what I was looking to do. What I had tried was along these lines but I was missing a few parts. Thank you!

Comment: i used the same. but i have one issue. Dialogview controller is appear perfectcly but when there are many entry elements and if we scroll to the bottom entry element, then keyboard is hiding that element. and that element does not auto scroll. can any one has any idea? i m creating dynamic form.

Comment: This helps me a lot!! You saved lot of time of mine!! Thanks :)

Comment: but i have only one issue. in my app, the first page is list page, which is UITableViewController, then i navigate to the appropriate form on selecting an item from the list. I have added radio button in one of my form which navigate further. but i see a back button on radio selection page, which brings me back to main list page. I want to hide the "Back" button on radio selection page. do you know how to achieve this?